# Similar to "burning a hole in my pocket" but for www shopping cart?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, internet

I like this: "Got three dollars burning a hole in my pocket".

Are there other expressions or phrases with similar meaning?

Actually, I want to know what the creative English speakers will write when they saw items furiously waiting on 'Wish List' or 'Shopping Cart' in the Internet shopping malls.

Because I feel like my monitor is burning in the corner every time I click-opened the mail from the my favorite book store.

Comment: In reference to the new credit cards with tap-n-go I'd probably say "I've got an itchy tapping-hand".

Comment: You might want to try asking this at the [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) site. I'm not sure what it means that items are furiously waiting. We should get that cleared up first before you dive into idioms.

Comment: In reference to what @CanisLupus says, I would point out that money burning in your pocket is used to describe a desire to spend your money. Your reference to "items furiously waiting on 'Wish List' seems more about a desire to obtain item X, and is therefore very different than a desire to spend money.

Comment: The idiom for wanting to spend money is *it's burning a hole in my pocket*.

Comment: I wear your granddad's clothes - I look incredible

Answer (score 1):

Actually "burning in my pocket" is not a common expression that I'm aware of.

"I've got three dollars burning a hole in my pocket (or wallet)." is the common form of the expression, as far as I'm aware.

As Robin said in a comment above, a desire to obtain an item is very different (from what this expression is meant to convey).

A strong desire to acquire items is sometimes expressed as having 'shopping fever'.

Comment: "shopping fever" is a great suggestion. (regarding the obvious typos in the question -- just edit them away!)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the compulsory behaviour that Internet shopping may create is part of a wider problem as shown below. As for a definition  I'd just call it *Internet shopping addiction* :

[Internet addiction disorder](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_addiction_disorder):  (from Wikipedia)

> - (IAD) is now more commonly called problematic internet use (PIU) or compulsive internet use (CIU).
> - IAD is often divided into subtypes by activity, such as excessive, overwhelming, or inappropriate internet pornography use, gaming, online social networking, blogging, email,**or internet shopping.**
>
>   - Internet addiction is a subset of a broader "technology addiction". Obsession with technology started with radio in the 1930s and with television in the 1960s, but has recently exploded in importance during the current digital.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***["shopaholic"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shopaholic)***?

> **noun**
>     informal 
>   
>   A compulsive shopper

You could simply say "I'm an internet shopaholic.

Comment: Someone who goes shopping while drunk.